# IOException on Deserializeling XML

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am writing a small navigation app for Windows Mobile 6.1 (.NET CF 3.5), and I am getting IOException when I try to deserialize my data from file stream, and I cant understand why.
here is some of my code:

```
//That's the class I am trying to serialize / deserialize
 public class MapData
    {
        [XmlIgnore]
        public Bitmap EntireMapBitmap { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public Route NavigationRoute { get; set; }
       //and some other unrelavant fields...
    }
```

here is the code to serialize:

```
string fileNameWithExtension = /*some calculation to get the full path*/
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MapData));
TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(fileNameWithExtension);
serializer.Serialize(textWriter, mapData);
textWriter.Close();
```

here is the code for deserialization:

```
 string fullPath = /*Retreive file's full path logic - working OK */;
 XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MapData));
 FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open);
 mapData = null;
 mapData = (MapData)deserializer.Deserialize(fs);
 fs.Close();
```

I know thats a lot of details, but from my interrogation, the Exception only occurs when I am making a use with the NavigationRoute poroperty, so I will add those related classes also...

```
 public class Route
{
    public List<GeographicCoordinate> Coordinates { get; set; }

    public Route()
    {
        Coordinates = new List<GeographicCoordinate>();
    }
}

public class GeographicCoordinate
{
    public int LocationOnMap_X { get; private set; }
    public int LocationOnMap_Y { get; private set; }

    public GeographicCoordinate(Point onMap)
    {
        LocationOnMap_X = onMap.X;
        LocationOnMap_Y = onMap.Y;
    }
}
```

As I mentioned before, its only after I add one or more objects to the Coordinates list of the Route - I get the exception (which makes it even more awkward to me...). Another thing I tried to do it to remove the private setters from GeographicCoordinate class - but it was no good.
Thanks everyone :)

Comment: If you're getting an exception you don't understand, *always* specify what's in the content of the exception.

Comment: @ET, when you say remove the private setters, do you mean you removed the private keyword or you removed the setter entirely? XmaSerializer requires that both get/set are available and public.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the actual exception, but I suspect that the problem is that your `GeographicCoordinate.LocationOnMap_X` and `GeographicCoordinate.LocationOnMap_Y` have private setters, you will need this to be public for XmlSerialization.